# Associate members to group using SenseNet.Client on Sensenet

Tags: c#, .net, sensenet

I am having issues defining the members of a group on sensenet using the .NET API SenseNet.Client.

I need to create an automatic process to add users and groups on sensenet. I know how to create the users and groups, but I didn't find any information about adding users to group.

Here's the code that I use to create a group:

```
var group = Content.CreateNew("/Root/IMS/BuiltIn/OUtest", "Group", "testGroup");
    group["Name"] = "testGroup";
    group["DisplayName"] = "testGroup";
    await group.SaveAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support this scenario, there is a **Group** class in the Client API that contains a couple of methods for modifying group membership. It inherits from the main *Content* class, so it has all its features.

If you already have a group id, you may choose the static API for modifying membership (the *idArray* below should contain *new members* only, you dot have to know existing members, this is only the 'delta').

```csharp
// add new members to a group
await Group.AddMembersAsync(group.Id, idArray);
```

...or the instance API, if you are creating a new Group (note the generic creator method):

```
// create group using the generic method
var group = Content.CreateNew<Group>("/Root/IMS/BuiltIn/OUtest", "Group", "testGroup");
group["Name"] = "testGroup";
group["DisplayName"] = "testGroup";
await group.SaveAsync();

// add new members
await group.AddMembersAsync(idArray);

// remove members
await group.RemoveMembersAsync(deletedUsersArray);
```

The methods above make the REST calls immediately, so there is *no need to call Save after them*.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice on method AddMemberAsync.